# How to use 'and' operator only if variable is set to "True"

Tags: python

How to use the `and` operator only if `use_ivr` = `True` ?

```
ivr = 30
use_ivr = True

if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and ivr > 30:
    print('yes')
```

So if `use_ivr` = `False`, it should execute as follows:

```
if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2:
    print('yes')
```

Comment: Where do you want to use the operator? in the if statement itself? what is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: `1 == 1 and 2 == 2` is always going to be true. Is that standing in for something?

Answer (score 1):

In python, the 2nd part of `and` is only executed when 1st part is true.
You can test this with an undefined veriable

```py
>>> if False and x # <- here x is undefined
        pass
#This won't raise an error since 1st part is False and it slipped the 2nd part of the expression.
```

What you need is to check `ivr>30` only when `use_ivr` is `True`. Kind of similar to how indicator variables are used to nullify a condition.

```py
if ((use_ivr and ivr > 30) or True) and 1 == 1 and 2 == 2:
    print('yes')
```

Here, If `use_ivr` is `True`, then `ivr` must be greater than 30
Or `True` meaning skip this check altogether of `use_ivr` is `False`.

Comment: ... Yeah that makes much more sense than my original comment: `if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and ((not use_ivr) or ivr > 30):`.....

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) method:**

```
ivr = 30
use_ivr = True

if all([1 == 1, 2 == 2, ivr > 30, use_ivr]):
    print('yes')

if all([1 == 1, 2 == 2, not use_ivr]):
    print('yes')
```

`all()` returns `True` if all the elements in the iterable

passed into the brackets are true (or if the iterable is empty), else, it returns `False`.

---

UPDATE:

Though my first code works fine, it evaluates `1 == 1, 2 == 2` twice. Here is an updated version:

```
ivr = 30
use_ivr = True

a = [1 == 1, 2 == 2, ivr > 30, use_ivr]

if all(a):
    print('yes')

if all(a[:2]+[not use_ivr]):
    print('yes')
```

Comment: One downside to this approach is that `1==1` and `2==2` get evaluated twice -- once for each conditional. Not a problem here, but something to consider before using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested if statement that checks if use_ivr is true:

```
ivr = 31
use_ivr = True

if use_ivr:
    if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2 and ivr > 30:
        print('yes')
else:
    if 1 == 1 and 2 == 2:
        print('no ivr was used');
```

Comment: Why use an `elif` instead of just `else`?

Comment: `elif not use_ivr` is redundant. Use `else` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea ninja'd ;)

Comment: Thought it was easier understandable with elif, but you guys are absolutely correct. I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, this is similar to many of the answers above.

```py
ivr = 31
use_ivr = True
ivr_condition = ivr > 30 if use_ivr else True

if (1==1) and (2==2) and ivr_condition:
  print('yes')
```

This solution opts to compress the ivr condition into a single ternary statement. You could inline this approach to have one longer line, though I personally found a single long line harder to parse.